# Given the following array, how do I print it out on multiple lines

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
```

I keep getting it in a single line, how can I print it out in the terminal so each array is on its own individual line like so:

```
[[1, 2, 3], 
 [8, 9, 4], 
 [7, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
puts array.to_s.gsub('],',"],\n")

#[[1, 2, 3],
# [8, 9, 4],
# [7, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: The thing is I still want it all to be inside one array, not just print the individual arrays inside of the main array line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing the mapped result of `#inspect` on `array`, like so:

```
puts array.map(&:inspect)

# [1, 2, 3]
# [8, 9, 4]
# [7, 6, 5]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's close, but the thing is, it is now printing three separate arrays, is there anyway I can print it inside one array, but the individual arrays line by line?

Comment: Looks like @sagarpandya has updated his answer to handle wrapping the output in a single array.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
   array.each do |sub|
     puts sub.join(", ")
   end
```

However, this will not include the [] characters, but will look like this:

```
1, 2, 3
8, 9, 4
7, 6, 5
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I usually end up doing whenever I want to display an array of arrays in my console like this.  I usually end up with something like `puts array.map{|a| a*", "}`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun - you can redefine `inspect` method like:

```
def array.inspect
  map(&:to_s).join("\n")
end
p array
# [1, 2, 3]
# [8, 9, 4]
# [7, 6, 5]
```